# How to change font color of $variables for php codes in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: php, variables, colors

As you can see it the color is only white, I want to change it to something unique color, I've already tried searching for a solution but no luck.

[image]

Comment: color doesn't affect your code, matter is code works or not

Comment: yeah I know that.. I just want it to have distinction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find xml file name  .tmtheme.xml
Find below code in file and replace string color as per your choice.

```
<dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Variable</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>variable</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>fontStyle</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#f7feed</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Comment: Sorry but where can I find .tmtheme.xml? I looked at destination folder of sublime can't find it.

Comment: oh no I don't use mac. But I think I know now how to edit it I'm just gonna follow the Package​Resource​Viewer.

Comment: Thank you very much btw.

Comment: well come. never forget to accept answer if got fixed

Comment: yeah sure Im new to stackoverflow